# How can I search for related words in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, if I search for "food," I want to return results that include any entry that has keyword "Restaurant" or "Chef" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the "synonyms" feature of Elasticsearch: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html

You define a list of words that you believe are synonyms (in your example - food, restaurant, chef) and then, at indexing time, ES will index not only "restaurant" for example, but also "food" and "chef". See more details about this in the link above.

Comment: Do you know of any available synonyms library for public use? Maybe some thesaurus copy or something?

Comment: Haven't tried this but according to [this link](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Default-Synonyms-td4028351.html) you could use Wordnet dictionary and use it in ES with `synonyms_path` as described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html)